# Plotting timeseries Bokeh chart with multiple categories

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have the following data in the dataframe:

```
df:
Category date   date_Count
0   CAT1 2017-05    144
1   CAT1 2017-11    67
2   CAT2 2017-06    76
3   CAT2 2017-11    57
4   CAT2 2018-04    220
5   CAT2 2018-07    52
```

There are ~ 8 differeent cats each sorted by time (Year + month)

I would like to plot the count values of time , with a bar for each category.

I was using Bokeh to do this, but failing miserably.

This is the furthest I got. I would like to make the values appear as labels on each bar.

[image: What I can make so far]

Thanks,

[EDIT] : Code:

```
counts=[]
countDates=df['date_Count'].Cat.dt.month]).agg('count')
months=np.arange(1.0, 12.0,1.0)
for month in months:
    if month in countDates[2018].keys():
        counts.append(countDates[2018][month])
    else:
         counts.append(0)

output_file('bokTest.html')
factors = [
    ("Q1", "jan"), ("Q1", "feb"), ("Q1", "mar"),
    ("Q2", "apr"), ("Q2", "may"), ("Q2", "jun"),
    ("Q3", "jul"), ("Q3", "aug"), ("Q3", "sep"),
    ("Q4", "oct"), ("Q4", "nov"), ("Q4", "dec"),

]


p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*factors), plot_height=350,
           toolbar_location='right')

p.vbar(x=factors, top=counts, width=0.9, alpha=0.5)
p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
show(p)
```

Comment: Please share code for what you have already tried

Comment: Sorry, updated with code

Comment: I'm not understanding what you want, that your current graph doesn't have.  You want the counts to be displayed over the bars instead of just using an axis?

Comment: Above is an example of one category. I want a bar for each month for each category, and also some hover label of counts.